# Terrible performance using transformblocks

Tags: performance, concurrency, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0, tpl-dataflow

I currently am trying to use TransformBlocks to make my code run faster. Instead, I find that I have achieved essentially no parallelization:

[image]

As you can see, there is quite a bit of dead space, with very little I/O or other issues preventing things from running in parallel (note: all the green blocks are the main thread).

The basic structure of the calling code is as follows:

```
var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 };
var download = new TransformBlock<string, Tuple<string, string>>(s => sendAndReciveRequest(s), options);
var process = new TransformBlock<Tuple<string, string, TransformBlock<string, Tuple<string, string>>>, List<string>>(s => Helpers.ParseKBDL(s), options);
var toObjects = new TransformBlock<List<string>, List<Food>>(list => toFood(list), options);

for (char char1 = 'a'; char1 < 'z' + 1; char1++)
    download.Post(char1.ToString());

while ((download.InputCount != 0 || download.OutputCount != 0 || process.InputCount != 0) || (Form1.downloadCount != Form1.processCount))
{
    if (download.OutputCount == 0 && download.InputCount == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    var res = download.Receive();
    process.Post(new Tuple<string, string, TransformBlock<string, Tuple<string, string>>>(res.Item1, res.Item2, download));
}
```

**Note:** The reason for the messy checks and tuples is because occasionally process needs to add more to the download block. I am very open to changing how this is organized.

So my question: Why is this code achieving no speedup? How can I restructure it so that I do get a speedup?

Comment: “As you can see, there is quite a bit of dead space, with very little I/O or other issues preventing things from running in parallel” I don't think you would see that in that chart. IO (whether synchronous or asynchronous) doesn't use any CPU, so you're not going to see it in the Cores view.

Comment: @svick I/O would be purple, synchronization would be red, etc. In any case, it all seems to be running on one thread. Why is that?

Comment: That's the Threads view, not the Cores view that you're showing here.

Comment: I'm confused by your code.  It seems that each time you get an output from the download block you post a reference to the download block to the process block with the results you just downloaded, rather than just post results straight back to the download block, making use of its queue.  It would certainly add overhead to do it the way you're doing it, though I don't know or expect that would account for the lack of parallelism.  Perhaps the reason is in Helpers.ParsseKBDL, which is not shown, which is serializing or synchronizing on all those download blocks running through it.

Comment: But basically, I'd just like to add that maybe you should look at TransformManyBlock which allows you to inject new items into the dataflow.

Comment: @davidbak in *some* cases, I need to throw out the results of the download block and add new items to it (many new items in fact). As far as transformMany, how does that handle the looping nature any better?